# resample a dataframe in-place

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to do in-place resampling of a pandas dataframe. I have a certain interface for various filters with the following signature:

```
def process(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
```

In most of the filters, I can do in-place filtering and one of the operations that I am struggling to do in-place is temporal resampling of my time series data.

I have something like:

```
def process(self, df):
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp').dt.tz_localize(None)
    df = df.resample('1H', on='timstamp').mean()
```

However, the changes to the `df` is not reflected back on the caller side. Is it possible to do this all in-place, so that the caller would see the changes?

Comment: is `df` an argument of your class? can you share an example of function that work for the inplace modification?

Comment: @Ben.T I actually do not know if it is possible to do this in-place. That is sort of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify it by slicing it and making a copy:

```
def process(self, df):
    df.loc[:, 'timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp').dt.tz_localize(None)
    df[:] = df.resample('1H', on='timstamp').mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This line:
`df[:] = df.resample('1H', on='timstamp').mean()` returns `single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Comment: @Luca Then there is really no way... You should just return it

Comment: cool, thanks for confirming. I will change the interfaces accordingly...